# how do I get the corresponding JSON value in my JSON object?

Tags: android, json, listview

Getting the `name` value in my `Toast` in `onItemClick` of my `ListView` I can do, but how do I get the `code` value?

I have a JSON array that looks like this :

```
 [
    {
      "code": "123",
      "name": "Jim"
    },
    {
      "code": "456",
      "name": "Sally"
    },
    {
      "code": "789",
      "name": "Bob"
    },
    {
      "code": "012",
      "name": "Jill"
    },
  etc...
  ]
```

I get the `name` value in my `ListView` like this :

```
public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();

        //  Create json array request
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                "http://www.nameofsite.com/nameoffile.php", (JSONArray)null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){
            public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray){
                // Successfully download json
                // So parse it and populate the listview
                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        items.add(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Log.e("Error", "Unable to parse json array");
            }
        });
        // Create request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        // add json array request to the request queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
```

And `Toast` of `name` in `onItemClick` like this :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        TextView myTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        String text = myTextView.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

But I want the `code` value in the `toast`, not the `name`. How can I do it?

Comment: Check Exception while you parse json. From code its seems to be ok.
or add log for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I want the code value in the toast, not the name

Then you need to actually parse the `"code"` from the JSON rather than **only** `"name"`, and add that to your adapter.

For example, parse it

```
String code = jsonObject.getString("code");
String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
items.add(code + " " + name);
```

And toast it

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        String[] parts = items.get(i).split(" ");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),parts[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put name value to name arraylist and code to code arraylist , In onItemclick you will use this position to get code from code arraylist because it have same index . Or you can test with hashmap

Answer (score -2):

Try this.

```
json.getJSONObject("jsonData").getString("name");
```

Comment: Where did `"jsonData"` come from?